# How to prevent sprintf error in R code

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several columns. Whenever a row value of column V2 is less than 20,  the character element on the same row in column V4 is to be replaced by a string "sp_NameOfTopElement_NameOfBottomElement"

My code:

```
R10 <- data$V4
positionBefore <- match(R10,R10)
itemBefore <- R10[c(NA, positionBefore)]

R10 <- rev(data$V4))
positionAfter <- match(R10, R10)-1
itemAfter <- rev(R10[c(NA, positionAfter)])

cond <- if data$V2 < 20
data$R10[cond] <- sprintf("sp_%s-%s", itemBefore[cond], itemAfter[cond])
```

After running my code, I got the following error:

```
Error in sprintf("sp_%s-%s", itemBefore[cond], itemAfter[cond]) :
arguments cannot be recycled to the same length
```

Checking my variables:

```
NROW(itemBefore[cond]) = 200
NROW(itemAfter[cond]) = 199
```

Obviously, two tow variables are unequal and I need to guard against this error.

my solution which did not work:

```
cond <- data$V2 < 20
if (any(itemAfter[cond]==0)){
    data$R10[cond] <- sprintf("sp_%s-%s", itemBefore[cond], "none")}
}else {data$R10[cond] <- sprintf("sp_%s-%s", itemBefore[cond], itemAfter[cond])}
```

How can I get my solution code to work? Thanks

EDIT:

head(raw data):

```
V1  V2 V3   V4
str 50  str2    pass
tre 13  stup1   plus
tre 70  vry plus
carq    60  rty plus
sty 17  tuc pass
```

head(expected result):

```
V1  V2 V3   V4
str 50  str2    pass
tre 13  stup1   sp_str_tre
tre 70  vry plus
carq    60  rty plus
sty 17  tuc sp_carq_?
```

My problem is the last row of the data, where there is no other row below that row, and hence we have a situation like: sty 17  tuc sp_carq_?. The "?" indicates no item below.

Comment: `cond <- if data$V2 < 20` This is wrong syntactically.

Comment: Can you post the result of `dput(data)` or otherwise `head(data)` if too lengthy? You're more likely to get answers that way.